# Reading large text file very slow

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, streamreader

so I have been given a task of writing a vb program where I read in a large .txt file (anywhere from 500mb to 2GB) and this files usually starts with a 13 digit number then loads of other info after per line. 
(e.g "1578597500548 info info info info etc.") I must let a user enter a 13 digit number and then my program search's the large file for that number at beginning of each line and if its found write the full line into a new .txt file!

My current program works perfectly but I'm noticing my adding to the list/streamreader part takes up around 90% of the process time. Averaging around 27secs per run. Any ideas how to speed up?
Here's what I have written.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim wtr As IO.StreamWriter
    Dim listy As New List(Of String)
    Dim i = 0

    stpw.Reset()
    stpw.Start()

    'reading in file of large data 700mb and larger
    Using Reader As New StreamReader("G:\USER\FOLDER\tester.txt")
        While Reader.EndOfStream = False
            listy.Add(Reader.ReadLine)
        End While
    End Using

    'have a textbox which finds user query number
    Dim result = From n In listy
                 Where n.StartsWith(TextBox1.Text)
                 Select n

    'writes results found into new file
    wtr = New StreamWriter("G:\USER\searched-number.txt")
    For Each word As String In result
        wtr.WriteLine(word)
    Next
    wtr.Close()

    stpw.Stop()
    Debug.WriteLine(stpw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds)

    Application.Exit()
End Sub
```

***UPDATE*** I've taken some suggestion about not putting it into a list first and just searching on memory, Time is about 5 seconds faster, still takes 23 seconds to complete and also its writing out the line above the digit im searching so if you could please tell me where i'm going wrong. Thanks guys!

```
wtr = New StreamWriter("G:\Karl\searchednumber.txt")
        Using Reader As New StreamReader("G:\Karl\AC\tester.txt")
            While Reader.EndOfStream = False
                lineIn = Reader.ReadLine
                If Reader.ReadLine.StartsWith(TextBox1.Text) Then
                    wtr.WriteLine(lineIn)

                Else

                    Continue While
                End If
            End While
            wtr.Close()
        End Using
```

Comment: Why are you loading the entire file into `listy` when you only need a single line? Get the input from the user, open the file, and start reading one line at at time and trying the match to the input. If it doesn't match, throw it away and move on to the next line. If it matches, you've already got the line, and you just stop reading the file.

Comment: See there could be more than 1 occurances of a 13 digit number so must search the whole file.

Comment: Yes, sure, but you are by now loading the whole file in memory, then you are creating an enumeration of those string for the query. You need to read each line and, when  it's a match, store it. Then move to the next. Do not store the string that don't match. LINQ is not your friend here.

Comment: If you want to use LINQ, then instead creating a `List(Of String)` to use as the enumerable source, use the [System.IO.File.ReadLines Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readlines?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_File_ReadLines_System_String_) that will create string iterator. i.e. `Dim result = From n In System.IO.File.ReadLines("G:\USER\FOLDER\tester.txt")`.

Comment: Updated to new code above

Comment: @TnTinMn That worked perfect! Slightly faster than my original at 24.8 seconds! Any more suggestions more than welcome!

Comment: If you have no need for the results other than to write them out to a file, then your updated approach is fine.

Comment: which text file would be as large as 2gb :-)

Comment: You don't need to load and store the entire file into memory in order to match one or more lines. Read what I wrote again.

Comment: Consumer-level spindle drives can read data at ~60MB/sec.  So a 2GB file will take 2048/60 = 34 seconds to read.  You're in the ballpark.  Spend money to get ahead.

Comment: Write a small program that simply reads the file, line by line, then time that and let us know how long that takes, then see if you can see a pattern. I/O is typically the most costly part of any operation.

Comment: Could that 13-digit "number" start with a "0"? If so, it may well be better to regard it as a string.

Comment: I'm curious... how often do you expect more than one occurance of the same number? Will most numbers be unique (only used once in the file)? When numbers are used more often, how often? Twice? Ten times? I may be able to tune list creation to **greatly** improve memory use depending on your answer.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Most numbers will be unique. But some may occur 2-5 times. About 75% will be unique

Comment: Then we can probably do a little better. By default, .Net lists create empty space for 10 items. Since we expect the Lists to only hold 1 item in the base case, and a handful in other cases, we may do better by setting an initial capacity between 1 and 3 in the List constructor. You'll need to measure to find what value works best for your data. Especially look at memory use. I updated my answer so you only need to change the integer value at the top of the class to try different values.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Awh amazing, but just to be clear say i set the capacity to 4 and turns out the same number showed up 5 times would that send an error? Sorry fairly new to all this!

Comment: No, there would be no error. This is only an initial capacity. If you have 4, and add the 5th item, the list will allocate a new buffer twice the size of the old one, copy all the old elements, and replace it. That's... expensive. But if it only happens occasionally, and only for small sets, letting it happen now and then can be a win. So you want an initial buffer size that probably only needs to double in size once for your largest values, and doesn't waste as much for your singles. Based on the "2-5 times" number, 2 or 3 should be big enough, depending on how often you get the "5"s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Index the file when the program loads.

Create a `Dictionary(Of ULong, Long)`, and when the program loads read through the file. For each line, add an entry to the dictionary showing the 13 digit value at the front of each line as the ULong key and the position in the file stream as the Long value.

Then, when a user puts in a key, you can check the dictionary, which will be almost instant, to find the exact location on disk you need and seek there directly.

*Building the file index at program start may take a few moments*, but you'll only ever have to do it **once**. Right now, you either need to search through the entire thing every time a user wants to do a search, or keep several hundred megabytes of text file data in memory. Once you have the index, looking up a value in the dictionary and then seeking directly to it should appear to happen almost instantly.

---

I just saw this comment:

> there could be more than 1 occurrences of a 13 digit number so must search the whole file.

Based on that, the index should be a `Dictionary(Of ULong, List(Of Long))`, where adding a value to entry first creates a list instance if one doesn't already exist, then adds the new value to the list.

Here's a basic attempt typed directly into the reply window without the aid of testing data or Visual Studio that likely therefore still contains several bugs:

```vb
Public Class MyFileIndexer
    Private initialCapacity As Integer = 1
    Private Property FilePath As String
    Private Index As Dictionary(Of ULong, List(Of Long))

    Public Sub New(filePath As String)
        Me.FilePath = filePath
        RebuildIndex()
    End Sub

    Public Sub RebuildIndex()
        Index = New Dictionary(Of ULong, List(Of Long))()

        Using sr As New StreamReader(FilePath)
            Dim Line As String = sr.ReadLine()
            Dim position As Long = 0
            While Line IsNot Nothing

                'Process this line
                If Line.Length > 13 Then
                   Dim key As ULong = ULong.Parse(Line.SubString(0, 13))
                   Dim item As List(Of Long)
                   If Not Index.TryGetValue(key, item) Then
                       item = New List(Of Long)(initialCapacity)
                       Index.Add(key, item)
                   End If

                   item.Add(position)
                End If

                'Prep for next line
                position = sr.BaseStream.Position
                Line = sr.ReadLine()
            End While
        End Using   
    End Sub

    'Expect key to be a 13-character numeric string
    Public Function Search(key As String) As List(Of String)
        'Will throw an exception if parsing fails. Be prepared for that.
        Dim realKey As ULong = ULong.Parse(key)
        Return Search(realKey)
    End Function

    Public Function Search(key As ULong) As List(Of String)
        Dim lines As List(Of Long)
        If Not Index.TryGetValue(key, lines) Then Return Nothing

        Dim result As New List(Of String)()
        Using sr As New StreamReader(FilePath)
            For Each position As Long In lines
                sr.BaseStream.Seek(position, SeekOrigin.Begin)
                result.Add(sr.ReadLine())
            Next position
        End Using
        Return Result
    End Function
End Class

'Somewhere public, when your application starts up:
Public Index As New MyFileIndexer("G:\USER\FOLDER\tester.txt")

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim lines As List(Of String) = Nothing
    Try
        lines = Index.Search(TextBox1.Text)
    Catch
        'Do something here
    End Try

    If lines IsNot Nothing Then
        Using sw As New StreamWriter($"G:\USER\{TextBox1.Text}.txt")
            For Each line As String in lines
                 sw.WriteLine(line)
            Next 
        End Using
    End If
End Sub
```

And for fun, here's a generic version of the class that lets you supply your own key selector function to index *any* file that stores a key with each line, which I could see being generally useful for, say, larger csv data sets.

```
Public Class MyFileIndexer(Of TKey)
    Private initialCapacity As Integer = 1
    Private Property FilePath As String
    Private Index As Dictionary(Of TKey, List(Of Long))
    Private GetKey As Func(Of String, TKey) 

    Public Sub New(filePath As String, Func(Of String, TKey) keySelector)
        Me.FilePath = filePath
        Me.GetKey = keySelector
        RebuildIndex()
    End Sub

    Public Sub RebuildIndex()
        Index = New Dictionary(Of TKey, List(Of Long))()

        Using sr As New StreamReader(FilePath)
            Dim Line As String = sr.ReadLine()
            Dim position As Long = 0
            While Line IsNot Nothing

               Dim key As TKey = GetKey(Line)
               Dim item As List(Of Long)
               If Not Index.TryGetValue(key, item) Then
                   item = New List(Of Long)(initialCapacity)
                   Index.Add(key, item)
               End If   
               item.Add(position)

                'Prep for next line
                position = sr.BaseStream.Position
                Line = sr.ReadLine()
            End While
        End Using   
    End Sub

    Public Function Search(key As TKey) As List(Of String)
        Dim lines As List(Of Long)
        If Not Index.TryGetValue(key, lines) Then Return Nothing

        Dim result As New List(Of String)()
        Using sr As New StreamReader(FilePath)
            For Each position As Long In lines
                sr.BaseStream.Seek(position, SeekOrigin.Begin)
                result.Add(sr.ReadLine())
            Next position
        End Using
        Return Result
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: This sounds exactly like what I have been looking for!! I havn't really used a list within a dictionary, any chance could just explain what I'd do a little more or example please?
I remember hearing some say they would use indexing

Comment: @K.Madden Wish granted

Comment: And now updated to better encapsulate the feature into a class

Comment: You are brilliant! Thank you so much for this. I shall try implement it tomorrow morning!! Thank you again! :)

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Is there an extra ( ) at the end of ` Private Index As Dictionary(Of ULong, List(Of Long))()` ? Studying the code. Thank you.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Does position need to be a long? `Dim position As Integer = 0`

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Does `Dim lines As List(Of Long)` need to be `Dim lines As New List(Of Long)`?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Does `Dim item As List(Of Long)` need to be `Dim item As 
 New List(Of Long)` ?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Should `Return SearchIndex(realKey)` be `Return Search(realKey)` ?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I see why `Dim item As List(Of Long)` should not be new. Sorry for the bother.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Can I use `Index.ContainsKey(key)` so I can avoid the green squiggly in both `Function Search(key As ULong)` and `Sub RebuildIndex()` ?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Sorry again, I get it now. It works like a .TryParse and fills in lines and item if True. I know the OP can figure this stuff out but I am much less experienced. Great code for me to study. Thank you.

Comment: @Mary Yes, there is an extra () and position should be long.  It is also correct to change `SearchIndex()` to just `Search()`.  Those are fixed. No, `lines As List(Of Long)` should not be `lines As New List(Of Long)`. The reference is assigned by the `TryGetValue()` function, or in the `If` block. Same for `item`... but you found that :) Not sure what you're seeing with `ContainsKey()`

Comment: Hi @JoelCoehoorn Finally testing your piece of code and in terms of speed, WOW! it is so fast longest part is just on application load when its building he index but still only about 8 seconds and search is instant. Only problem I'm seeing is what ever number I'm searching it will print out what seems the number after it line? so like say number I'm searching for is on line 345 it will print whatever is on 346? Been trying change start positions and all but no luck! Sorry about this

Comment: @K.Madden Should be fixed now.

Comment: hi @JoelCoehoorn, so its printing the line and doing it fast but it seems to be printing out half through the line now, I noticed maybe its because a lot of the number a begin with a 0? also in some cases the 13 digit number appears half way through the line too. Thank you

Comment: From my own research I think the error or bug for me anyways seems to be in the "position = sr.BaseStream.Postion" line. It starts off at 0. Then as goes reads through file changes to 5120,9216,13312,17408 etc. Is this meant to be right?

Comment: It seems to almost be adding around 1024 onto each start position. So say line one position starts 0 end 4096, next position should be 4097? but instead going to 5120. This appears to be what's making it start some lines halfway through

Comment: So I have changed that one line to `position += 4097` and when there is only 1 occurrence of the number in question works perfect. But if there is 2 occurrence the first one seems to be perfect but the second one starts off okay but then seems to start again half way through?